# Removing ambiguity when passing null to a function in C#

Tags: c#

I have two functions which differ only in their second parameter.
Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> Get(string clause, List<Things> list)
{
}

public IEnumerable<Thing> Get(string clause, List<OtherThing> list)
{
}
```

I want to call the first instance of this function, but I want to pass null as the second parameter. Is there a way to specify the "type" of null?

Comment: FWIW: I would probably change the design to always require/accept a colleciton, even if empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast the null literal:

```
Get("", (List<Things>)null)
```

store it in a variable first:

```
List<Things> list = null;
Get("", list);
```

Use reflection. (I'm not going to show an example because it's needlessly complicated.)

Comment: I had thought about the second solution, but I didn't like the way it looked. I thought the first one would actually throw an exception, but you are correct that it wont. Thanks.